# Creating matrix based on a dataframe and storing weights in matrix cells

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr

I have this dataframe :-

```
pf = structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:21, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(101L, 
61L, 84L, 98L, 56L, 222L, 137L, 103L, 136L, 97L, 77L, 110L, 84L, 
88L, 92L, 89L, 86L, 87L, 84L, 71L, 36L), Relative_freq = c(0.0505252626313157, 
0.0305152576288144, 0.0420210105052526, 0.0490245122561281, 0.0280140070035018, 
0.111055527763882, 0.0685342671335668, 0.0515257628814407, 0.0680340170085043, 
0.0485242621310655, 0.0385192596298149, 0.0550275137568784, 0.0420210105052526, 
0.0440220110055028, 0.0460230115057529, 0.0445222611305653, 0.0430215107553777, 
0.0435217608804402, 0.0420210105052526, 0.0355177588794397, 0.0180090045022511
)), .Names = c("Var1", "Freq", "Relative_freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now i want to create a matrix based on this dataframe, which will store these relative_freq as edge(matrix cells) weights.

Heres the code :-

```
k=5
PF = matrix(data=NA, nrow=k, ncol=k)

for(i in 1:k){
  for(j in 1:k){
    pf = PageFreq(pf,i,j)
    a = pf[[1]]
    b = pf[[2]]
    PF[i,j] = 2 * a *b/(a + b)

  }
}
```

and here is the PageFreq function which i need to get tweaked in order to work correct :-

```
PageFreq = function(pf,i,j){

  a = pf %>% filter(Var1 == i) %>% select(Relative_freq);
  b = pf %>% filter(Var1 == j) %>% select(Relative_freq);
  c = list(a,b);
  return (c)

}
```

Please look whats the correct way ! Thanks

Comment: Please show the desired output.

Comment: so its 5*5 matrix according to demo but actually its a 21*21 matrix and its frist row data like "     [,1]                       [,2]                       [,3]                       [,4]                      
[1,] "Harmonic mean of 1 and 1" "Harmonic mean of 1 and 2" "Harmonic mean of 1 and 3" "Harmonic mean of 1 and 4"
     [,5]                      
[1,] "Harmonic mean of 1 and 5""

Comment: Update the information in your post, not in the comment. It is difficult to read your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the working code :-

```
PageFreq = function(pf,i,j){

  a = pf %>% filter(Var1 == i) %>% select(Relative_freq);
  b = pf %>% filter(Var1 == j) %>% select(Relative_freq);
  a1 = a$Relative_freq
  b1 = b$Relative_freq
  c = list(a1,b1);
  return (c)

}
k = 21
PF = matrix(data=NA, nrow=k, ncol=k)

for(i in 1:k){
  for(j in 1:k){
    pff = PageFreq(pf,i,j)
    a = pff[[1]]
    b = pff[[2]]
    PF[i,j] = 2 * a *b/(a + b)

  }
}
```